# Where to “--exclude” the specific directory's in mine backup script using tar

Tags: backup, tar

I want to backup my whole linux server but where do i --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=/var/backups . Please help!!!

Here is my code. I may also have some errors in it. Feedback is welcome.....

```
#!bin/bash
#Purpose = Backup of var directory

TIME=`date +"%b-%d-%y"`  # This Command will add date in Backup File Name.
FILENAME="backup-$TIME.tar.gz"  # Here i define Backup file name format.
SRCDIR="/ "    # Location of Important Data Directory (Source of backup).
DESDIR="/var/backups/fullbackup"    # Destination of backup file.
LOGSYS="/var/log/fullbackup"   #Log files of the backup.

echo "Starting backup of $SRCDIR to $DESDIR on $TIME" >> ${LOGSYS}
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
echo "Ending backup of $SRCDIR on $TIME" >> ${LOGSYS}

#END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You list all the directories to be excluded into a text file, like this :

```
/var/backups
/proc
/sys
/dev
/tmp
```

Let's call this file `/etc/backup-excl.lst`

Then you can call the `tar` command the following way :

```
tar ScpfzX /etc/backup-excl.lst $DESTDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

The X parameter flas is to tell that a file with directories to be excluded will follow.

The S parameter is used to handle Linux sparse files smartly. *Sparse files* are files which contain empty space, where the disk space is pre-allocated but not necessarily used. Handling these files smartly means only backuping the real content, not the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

To add exclude option just append it after:

```
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR --exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=/var/backups
```

The better way is to add variable with exclude options, like:

```
EXCLUDE="--exclude=proc --exclude=sys --exclude=dev/pts --exclude=/var/backups"
```

After that your tar command should look like:

```
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR $EXCLUDE
```